# embedded logos in menu bars

Tags: html, css

I want to know how some sites embedded their logos. I was looking at some source of popular sites expecting to see a .svg or image that would display the logo. However I found an `<a>`elements like:

```
<a href="/" class="logo js-gtm-event" data-gtm-action="logo" data-gtm-event="navigation" data-gtm-label="clicked">LOGO NAME logo</a>
```

How does that above code get transformed into a logo? Is data-gtm-action a custom attribute? Trying to work out what's going on here and I'm new to UI design.

Comment: Did you check the CSS for `background: url(/logo.svg);`?

Comment: hi Simon, No i didn't i didn't think of that...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you can see in this link, you have a class:"logo ... the logo class contains probably some background-image css information.

Edit: and regarding the data attribut, you have a description here: http://www.w3schools.com/tags/att_global_data.asp

This attribute is very convenient to pass values without using input type="hidden".